# Fast Array comparison in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have two integer arrays that has 11059200 elements. From below example,

I am doing for changing the value of array `d1` to 0 by comparing index of element in `d2`

The calculating time of below program is

```
Comparing started: 2019-03-02 08:45:56 +0000
Comparing finished: 2019-03-02 08:46:00 +0000
```

This process took 4 seconds is more time.

I want to reduce time. Is there any possibilities available? Thank you

```
var d1 = [Int]()
var d2 = [Int]()

let value = 11059200

for _ in 0...value{

    d1.append(Int.random(in: 0...value))
    d2.append(Int.random(in: 0...value))
}

print("Comparing started: \(Date())")

var _ = d1.enumerated().compactMap { (index,value) -> Int in

    return d2[index] == value ? 0 : value
}

print("Comparing finished: \(Date())")
```

**Update:**

As per Alexander's comment, I am using map to reduce time from 2-3 seconds

```
var _ = d1.enumerated().map { (index,value) -> Int in
  return d2[index] == value ? 0 : value
}
```

Comment: Would having them sorted by faster?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I need `index` & `element`. So, It should not be sorted...

Comment: "This process took 4 seconds is more time." ???

Comment: You're discarding the result of this entire operation. So what exactly are you trying to do?'

Comment: @Alexander, The result of the entire operation is important for me. I am trying to reduce the mapping time. I don't know what I need to use. So, I used `compactMaping` to compare. But it takes 4 seconds to finish the loop.

Comment: @Aishu You could probably speed it up by using a simple `map` instead of `compactMap`. You're not returning an Optional (sort of), so you have no need to use `compactMap`. In fact, your expression `d2[index] == value ? 0 : value` is being implicitly promoted to optional, only for `compactMap` to then have to spend time unwrapping it.

Comment: @Alexander, Ok. I updated the question with your suggestion. Is it exactly you said? Now it's taking 2 seconds some time 3 seconds to finish the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably speed it up by using a simple map instead of compactMap. You're not returning an Optional (sort of), so you have no need to use compactMap. In fact, your expression d2[index] == value ? 0 : value is being implicitly promoted to optional, only for compactMap to then have to spend time unwrapping it.

Additionally, you can simplify the code by using `zip` to iterate the 2 sequences together:

```
import Foundation

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: String, operation: () -> Void) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

let max = 11059200

let d1 = (0...max).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0...max) }
let d2 = (0...max).map { _ in Int.random(in: 0...max) }

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "Enumerating and indexing, comparing using compactMap (original)") {
    let result = d1.enumerated().compactMap { index, value -> Int in
        return d2[index] == value ? 0 : value
    }

    print(result.count)
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "Enumerating and indexing, comparing using map") {
    let result = d1.enumerated().map { index, value -> Int in
        return d2[index] == value ? 0 : value
    }

    print(result.count)
}

// just for a benchmark, don't write codel like this.
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "Manual Indexing") {
    var result = Array<Int>()
    result.reserveCapacity(d1.count)
    for i in d1.indices {
        let (d1Value, d2Value) = (d1[i], d2[i])
        let newValue = d1Value == d2Value ? 0 : d1Value
        result.append(newValue)
    }

    print(result.count)
}

// "Best" from a readibility stand-point
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "Zip") {
    let result = zip(d1, d2).map { d1Value, d2Value in
        return d1Value == d2Value ? 0 : d1Value
    }

    print(result.count)
}
```

Here are the preliminary results, in a non-optimized build. These are ***absolutely meaningless***. The goal of debug builds is for the compiler to produce a correct, runnable program in the shortest time possible, with absolutely 0 attention given to performance. It's great for fast development iteration, but it's useless for bench marking.

> Time elapsed for Enumerating and indexing, comparing using compactMap (original): 6.206556916236877 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Manual Indexing: 0.3380240201950073 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Zip: 7.123739957809448 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Enumerating and indexing, comparing using map: 5.2529460191726685 s.

When you turn on optimization (The `-O` flag in the `swiftc` cli, or as an option in your Xcode build target), you get a completely different picture:

> Time elapsed for Enumerating and indexing, comparing using compactMap (original): 0.5904990434646606 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Enumerating and indexing, comparing using map: 0.22207605838775635 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Manual Indexing: 0.18644499778747559 s.
>
> Time elapsed for Zip: 0.2339940071105957 s.

I would recommend the `zip` based approach for its readability. If performance is *absolutely* critical, to the point where you've determined that it's okay to sacrifice readability and maintainability for tiny speed perks, then it might be worthwhile to switch to manual indexing, but that's very unlikely to be the case.